# How to fetch and display data from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and i am stuck, i have two models,

lodge.rb

```
class Lodge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lodgedetails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lodgedetails
end
```

lodgedetail.rb

```
class Lodgedetail  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lodge
end
```

lodge_controller.rb

```
def show   
    @lodge = Lodge.all
    @lodgedetails = Lodgedetail.all
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @lodgedetails.each do |l|%>
    <tr>
        <td><%= l.lodge.name %></td>
        <td><%= l.lodge.address %></td>
        <td><%= l.lodge.about %></td>

        <td><%=  l.try(:contact) %></td>
        <td><%=  l.try(:email) %></td>

        <td><%= l.lodge.facility %></td>
        <td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Now when i have 2contacts,2emails for a lodge,it will display the entire row twice. How do i modify it so that it will display record once,and if the contact field or email field has 2 values,it should be displayed in same row like

```
name address about contact1,contact2  email1,email2  facility
```

instead of

```
name address about contact1 email1 facility
name address about contact2 email2 facility
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<% @lodge.each do |l|%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= l.name %></td>
    <td><%= l.address %></td>
    <td><%= l.about %></td>
    <td>
      <% l.lodgedetails.each do |ld| %>
        <%= ld.contact %>,
        <%= ld.email %>,
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= l.facility %></td>
    <td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this works but it creates 4 cells contact1,email1,contact2,email2. IS there any way to have just 2cells,1 for contacts and 1for emails?

Comment: Yes, write the internal loop twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the way you iterate

```
<% @lodge.each do |ldge|%>
    <tr>
  <% ldge.lodgedetails.each do |l|%>

        <td><%= l.lodge.name %></td>
        <td><%= l.lodge.address %></td>
        <td><%= l.lodge.about %></td>

        <td><%=  l.try(:contact) %></td>
        <td><%=  l.try(:email) %></td>

        <td><%= l.lodge.facility %></td>
        <td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></td>

    <% end %>

    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

You dont need to do this

```
@lodgedetails = Lodgedetail.all
```

Rails way is

```
@lodge[0].lodgedetails
```

Comment: result is same, it displays 2 rows.

Comment: Besides views, explain what data you have in db and which are all you wanna print

Comment: Lodge table - id,name,address,about,facility
  Lodgedetails table - id,contact,email 
so some lodge can have 1contact and 1email and some may have 2contacts,2emails. So in view in 1cell i have to display both contacts like contact1,contact2 , but now its creating 2 separate rows.